# How to automate the backup of Dell switch

Tags: backup, automation, switch, switching

We are trying to automate the configuration backup of Dell L2 switch N2048.
Switch is in the network with SSH, HTTPS enabled, and Telnet disabled.
Steps we've tried:

1. **Plink** – we could connect successfully with a cmd

   ```
   plink.exe -ssh admin@SWITCHIP -pw password
   ```

   But we can't automate the rest with commandline. At least we couldn't find after extensive Googling. There aren't any bash/Perl experts in-house. So that gate's closed as well. We are checking options of pushing in the following commands

   ```
   enable 
   copy running-config tfpt://server/share/run.txt
   ```
2. **SNMP MIB** – we did come across the MIB, but could not completely get through; as we assume we will need to upgrade firmware. We are in the process of upgrading it. As this is a production environment, we are ruling out this option. [[ref]](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/network-switches/f/866/t/19440282)

Things we don't need:

1. Any paid tools like Dell open Manage network manager

Comment: And what exactly is the "dell switch" please that you need to "automate the backup" of?

Comment: Product recommendation questions are off topic here. If you reword your question to focus on solving the problem instead of asking what specific software to use, and tell us exactly what hardware you are working with and how it is connected to the computer you are running the "backup" from, then we may be able to help.

Comment: @pulsarjune: (1) I presume that you are the same person as Jobin Joseph. If so, you should use the [contact form](//superuser.com/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged. (2) As I recall, `plink` is usually used with `expect`.  Have you investigated `expect`?

Comment: @Scott Jobin is my collegue of mine. I was more aware of what his requirement was!

Answer (score 0):

We were able to achieve this with [Kitty](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/?page=Command-line%20options)
Below is the command line we've used to automate with a cmd script.

```
kitty.exe DeviceIP -ssh -v -l username -pw password
-cmd "enable \n Copy Startup-Config tftp://tftpserverIP/dev_runconfig.txt \ny \n logout"
```

This might differ depending on the device, but this helps build the basic script.

Answer (score 0):

Using plink.exe this should work:

```
plink -ssh admin@SWITCHIP -pw password -m commands.txt
```

The command.txt should hold the commands you want to send to the switch.